# Create and download an UTF8 plain text file from JS (browser)

Tags: javascript, data-uri

I'm stucking on a problem that I cannot understand.
I got an HTML page, declaring `<meta charset="utf-8" />`, attempting to create and download  a text file, containing some UTF8 characters.
The text is stored inside a JS variable and I'm trying to download the variable content as text file using the DataURI API.
This is the code:

```
const myText = "àòùè";
const uriContent = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64," + btoa(myText);
const element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', uriContent);
element.setAttribute('download', "example_filename.log");
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

The resulting file is saved as ISO8859-15 and not in UTF-8 as declared in dataURI.
It results in strange characters due to wrong encoding.

The encoding is checked using the `file` command under UNIX:

```
file example_filename.log
example_filename.log: ISO-8859 text
```

Comment: How exactly do you determine that "the resulting file is saved as ISO8859-15"?

Comment: Using the file command under LINUX (or opening in various IDEs). I add these infos in question body in order to re-open the issue

Comment: The `file` command is just giving you a best guess. There's nothing in the file that declares what encoding it's in. Have you simply tried opening the file in a text editor as UTF-8? Do the characters come out correct?

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. In Chrome and Firefox, `btoa('€')` throws as the euro sign is outside the Latin1 range

Comment: By the way, you can call `.click()` without appending the element to the document

Comment: Yes opening in text editor (or IDEs) I can see correct characters only configuring it in ISO8859-15. The EURO character seems not to be supported by btoa.
Could be the btoa the problem?

Comment: It works for me with any text (Chinese, Hindi, Japanese) with leaving out `base64` encoding: `const uriContent = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + myText;`